# Cannot convert value of type '(NSError!, SPTSession!) -> Void' to expected argument type 'SPTAuthCallback!'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to follow a tutorial ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeO00YdJ3cE) and I just converted my application to the latest Swift3-Syntax.
Unfortunately there are still some errors, which I just cannot fix.
I would appreciate **any tips.**

The errors:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnbAz.png)

**My AppDelegate.swift:**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    let kClientID = "cfa6ab909e8349bcb78d4924e1d7a32c"
    let kCallbackURL = "spotifytutorial://returnAfterLogin"
    let kTokenSwapURL = "http://localhost:1234/swap"
    let kTokenRefreshServiceURL = "http://localhost:1234/refresh"

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

        if SPTAuth.defaultInstance().canHandle(url, withDeclaredRedirectURL: URL(string: kCallbackURL)) {
            SPTAuth.defaultInstance().handleAuthCallback(withTriggeredAuthURL: url, tokenSwapServiceEndpointAt: URL(string: kTokenSwapURL), callback: { (error:NSError!, session:SPTSession!) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    print("AUTHENTICATION ERROR")
                    return
                }

                let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

                let sessionData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: session)

                userDefaults.set(sessionData, forKey: "SpotifySession")

                userDefaults.synchronize()

                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "loginSuccessfull"), object: nil)


           })
        }

        return false

    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

**My ViewController.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, SPTAudioStreamingPlaybackDelegate {

    let kClientID = "cfa6ab909e8349bcb78d4924e1d7a32c"
    let kCallbackURL = "spotifytutorial://returnAfterLogin"
    let kTokenSwapURL = "http://localhost:1234/swap"
    let kTokenRefreshServiceURL = "http://localhost:1234/refresh"

    var session:SPTSession!
    var player:SPTAudioStreamingController?

    @IBOutlet weak var artworkImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loginButton.isHidden = true
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateAfterFirstLogin), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "loginSuccessfull"), object: nil)

        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

        if let sessionObj:AnyObject = userDefaults.object(forKey: "SpotifySession") as AnyObject? { // session available
            let sessionDataObj = sessionObj as! Data

            let session = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: sessionDataObj) as! SPTSession

            if !session.isValid() {
                SPTAuth.defaultInstance().renewSession(session, withServiceEndpointAt: URL(string: kTokenRefreshServiceURL), callback: { (error:NSError!, renewdSession:SPTSession!) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        let sessionData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(session)
                        userDefaults.setObject(sessionData, forKey: "SpotifySession")
                        userDefaults.synchronize()

                        self.session = renewdSession
                        self.playUsingSession(renewdSession)
                    }else{
                        println("error refreshing session")
                    }
                })
            }else{
                print("session valid")
                self.session = session
                playUsingSession(session)
            }



        }else{
            loginButton.isHidden = false
        }


    }


    func updateAfterFirstLogin () {
        loginButton.isHidden = true

        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

        if let sessionObj:AnyObject = userDefaults.object(forKey: "SpotifySession") as AnyObject? {
            let sessionDataObj = sessionObj as! Data
            let firstTimeSession = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: sessionDataObj) as! SPTSession
            self.session = firstTimeSession
            playUsingSession(firstTimeSession)

        }

    }


    func playUsingSession(_ sessionObj:SPTSession!){
        if player == nil {
            player = SPTAudioStreamingController(clientId: kClientID)
            player?.playbackDelegate = self
        }

        player?.login(with: sessionObj, callback: { (error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print("Enabling playback got error \(error)")
                return
            }

            /*SPTRequest.requestItemAtURI(NSURL(string: "spotify:album:4L1HDyfdGIkACuygktO7T7"), withSession: sessionObj, callback: { (error:NSError!, albumObj:AnyObject!) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    println("Album lookup got error \(error)")
                    return
                }

                let album = albumObj as SPTAlbum

                self.player?.playTrackProvider(album, callback: nil)
            })*/

            SPTRequest.performSearch(withQuery: "let it go", queryType: SPTSearchQueryType.queryTypeTrack, offset: 0, session: nil, callback: { (error:NSError!, result:AnyObject!) -> Void in
                let trackListPage = result as SPTListPage

                let partialTrack = trackListPage.items.first as SPTPartialTrack

                SPTRequest.requestItemFromPartialObject(partialTrack, withSession: nil, callback: { (error:NSError!, results:AnyObject!) -> Void in
                    let track = results as SPTTrack
                    self.player?.playTrackProvider(track, callback: nil)
                })


            })

        })

    }


    @IBAction func loginWithSpotify(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let auth = SPTAuth.defaultInstance()

        let loginURL = auth?.loginURL(forClientId: kClientID, declaredRedirectURL: URL(string: kCallbackURL), scopes: [SPTAuthStreamingScope])

        UIApplication.shared.openURL(loginURL!)
    }


    func updateCoverArt(){
        if player?.currentTrackMetadata == nil {
            artworkImageView.image = UIImage()
            return
        }

        let uri = player?.currentTrackMetadata[SPTAudioStreamingMetadataAlbumURI] as! String

        SPTAlbum.albumWithURI(URL(string: uri), session: session) { (error:NSError!, albumObj:AnyObject!) -> Void in
            let album = albumObj as SPTAlbum

            if let imgURL = album.largestCover.imageURL as NSURL! {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in
                    var error:NSError? = nil
                    var coverImage = UIImage()

                    if let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL, options: nil, error: &error){
                        if error == nil {
                            coverImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!
                        }
                    }

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        self.artworkImageView.image = coverImage
                    })


                })
            }

        }

    }


    func audioStreaming(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController!, didStartPlayingTrack trackUri: URL!) {
        updateCoverArt()
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: You probably have to change `NSError` to `Error`

Comment: Just a small advice: let the pre-compiler tell you what's the parameter's type by calling a closure like `functionWithClosure { param1, param2 in ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

On your delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

    if SPTAuth.defaultInstance().canHandle(url) {

        SPTAuth.defaultInstance().handleAuthCallback(withTriggeredAuthURL: url, callback: {
            error, session in

            if error != nil {
                print("AUTHENTICATION ERROR \(error)")
                return
            }

            let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

            let sessionData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: session)

            userDefaults.set(sessionData, forKey: "SpotifySession")

            userDefaults.synchronize()

            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "loginSuccessfull"), object: nil)
            })
    }
    return false

}
```

And on the Controller:

```
func loginWithSpotify(sender: AnyObject) {
    let auth = SPTAuth.defaultInstance()!

    auth.clientID = clientId
    auth.redirectURL = URL(string: kCallbackURL)
    auth.tokenRefreshURL = URL(string: kTokenRefreshServiceURL)
    auth.tokenSwapURL = URL(string: kTokenSwapURL)
    auth.requestedScopes = [SPTAuthPlaylistReadPrivateScope ]

    let loginURL = auth.loginURL


    UIApplication.shared.openURL(loginURL!)
}
```